# enable/disable "Whole program optimization" (/GL) in property sheet (.props)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, propertysheet

In project property > `C/C++ > Optimization > Whole Program Optimization`, I can set `/GL`.

Can I enable/disable the `/GL` in a shared property-sheet (`.props` file) and make many projects bases from it?

I have tried :-

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <WholeProgramOptimization 
    Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
      true
 </WholeProgramOptimization>
```

However, it looks like there is no effect.
Do I really have to edit the property of each project manually?

I am using VS2017 Version 15.3.0.

Related: [Visual Studio property sheets: Why is Character Set missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343438/visual-studio-property-sheets-why-is-character-set-missing)

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you actually apply this sheet to project configuration?

Comment: @VTT I imported via Property Manager i.e. `<ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'"> ... <Import Project="..\someDir\someSheet.props" />` in `.vcxproj`.  I will verify it again. Thank.

Comment: @VTT I tried to set it in property sheet, but the whole program optimization setting in "project property page" (the popup that can be chosen when right click on a project in "Solution Explorer") still appear as "no".  ... The performance of the final exe is also same as "no".  .... Are you using VS2017 or different version?

Comment: I'm using VS2017 15.9.12

Comment: @VTT Thank, that tells me something .... interesting.

Comment: Note the Condition you used for the ImportGroup.  Only active for the Debug configuration, not for Release.  Delete that Condition.  Best to use the "visual" in Visual Studio, View > Other Windows > Property Manager.

Comment: @cppBeginner Did you get it working? I'm trying the same thing, but without the condition, because we already have a dedicated propsheet for release builds. But for some reason the option doesn't show up in the projects which inherit this propsheet. I tried adding `Label="Configuration"` to the PropertyGroup, because that's how it shows up in a vcxproj file, but that didn't help either.

Comment: @Simpleton :: If my memory is still correct, I couldn't find the answer.  However, after I measure the performance, the flag result ranged from very little positive to minor negative (-20% to +5%).  Thus, I have stopped using the flag altogether.

Comment: I tried to use the Property Manager to create a new propsheet containing the option, but it doesn't turn up there either. I guess that's because it's a meta setting. So I ended up using the actual settings instead, see below. I didn't do a performance test, sizewise it has only minor effects for me, but it tripled the build time.

`<ItemDefinitionGroup><ClCompile><WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization></ClCompile>   <Link>     <LinkTimeCodeGeneration>UseLinkTimeCodeGeneration</LinkTimeCodeGeneration></Link>`

Answer (score 0):

To do this setting using your own property sheet, this one must be included by the projects (.vcxproj) **before** the `Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props`.

Otherwise, the properties at the project level will looks good, but not the one used for the CL tasks of the .c(pp).

For example, assuming the following `D:\shared\my-customization.props` sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
    <MY_CUSTOMIZATION_PREAMBLE>1</MY_CUSTOMIZATION_PREAMBLE>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>false</WholeProgramOptimization>
     // some others settings suffers from the same restrictions
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <UseDebugLibraries Condition="'$(Configuration)'!='Release'">true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <UseDebugLibraries Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">false</UseDebugLibraries>

    <_PropertySheetDisplayName>MyCustomization preamble</_PropertySheetDisplayName>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

To share them on your several projects, it must be included on theirs .vcxproj like this:

```
[...]
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    [...]
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="D:\my-customization.props" Condition="'$(MY_CUSTOMIZATION_PREAMBLE)' == ''" />
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
     [...]
  </PropertyGroup>
  [...]
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    [ usual location to import the property sheet ]
```